# Updating phonegap JSON dynamically (android)

Tags: android, json, cordova

*Note: My problem might be a bit confusing. I will try to explain it clearly, but in case you think something is missing, please let me know in the comments.*

I am creating an Android app using phonegap. My app uses some data which is fed into the app using JSON. I plan to ship my app with a JSON which looks something like:

```
{
"8": [ {"subject":"Sample","room":"L2"} ],
"9": [ {"subject":"something","room":"L3"} ]
}
```

**Problem I am facing**

As time passes, the values of JSON may have to be changed. For example, `"Sample"` may need to be changed to `"hello"`. 
**These changes have to be made by me from the cloud.** So that, when the users are connected to the internet and they press the "update" button, these changes in the JSON stored in their device should take place.

Note: **I have already set up hosting and my app can access the updated json at a domain www.example.com/world.json **

How can I copy the contents of world.json and put them into the native JSON which is present in my user's device?
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: So you essentially want to download JSON?

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal, yes, I want to download JSON and replace the existing JSON with the new JSON on the android device.

Comment: What's the relation to PhoneGap?

Comment: The app is made in HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT and is converted to android using phonegap.

Comment: So you're not coding this in Java? Sorry I'm not familiar with PhoneGap.

Comment: I posted a answer assuming that you are using JavaScript as cordova is a tag. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to make a remote ajax call, get the latest JSON, replace the existing one.
I am assuming that you are storing the existing JSON in localStorage

So, you will have a logic that sets that localStorage value as what you want on the 1st run

```
if(firstRun){
    myjson={
           "8": [ {"subject":"Sample","room":"L2"} ],
           "9": [ {"subject":"something","room":"L3"} ]
    }
    window.localStorage("json", JSON.stringify(myjson));
```

Then on click of update button or some other event from user, you can get the new JSON and replace the existing one in localStorage

```
function onclick(){
    $.post( "www.example.com/world.json", function( data ) {
        window.localStorage("json", JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

And where ever you want to use that JSON,

```
var myjson=JSON.parse(window.localStorage("json"))
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. But I have a large number of json and I can't store data in localStorage, but instead, I have .json files in the directory. Can I replace those?

Comment: yes, of course. You can use all of localStorage/ browser DB/ SQL Lite

Comment: Link to one of SQL Lite plugins - https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: Actually, I have a file `sample.json` already created and shipped with the app. Can I make changes **in that file** and replace it with the file at www.example.com/world.json ?

Comment: yes, you will need a app update for that, where in you add a update button in your app that replaces the existing file like described above. Problem is, I am assuming too much about your app as I have limited knowledge of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AkshayArora: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as complete :)

Comment: @divyenduz This is too old post but I hope you can help me too. I have some sort of same problem. I have developed an android app using html,css,js and phonegap. I have this file called data.json that is located inside www. Is there anyway that I host this data.json in my server and when user is connected to internet, app checks the size of local data.json and server data.json if there's difference, app downloads the server data.json and replace it in local system. web version of my app is http://liquor.pushpan.com.np/